# Swift Parse - UITableViewAutomaticDimension when downloading images from parse they are the incorrect size until I scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have added a table view, and I am display image in the cells. I have also added this code:

So that the cells resize depending on the image.

When I launch my app though, I get this :

[[image]]

And the images do not load untill I start scrolling...If I scroll down half the page then go back to the top, I get this: Which is correct

[image]

Any ideas? I have researched on google and tried the odd solution for the older versions of Xcode, But nothing seems to work!

Here is the rest of my code from the TableViewController:

```
extension TimelineViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 46
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return timelineComponent.content.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostHeader") as! PostHeaderTableViewCell

        let post = self.timelineComponent.content[section]
        headerCell.post = post


        return headerCell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as! PostTableViewCell

        //cell.postImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Background.png")

        let post = timelineComponent.content[indexPath.section]
        post.downloadImage()
        post.fetchLikes()
        cell.post = post

        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
}

extension TimelineViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        timelineComponent.targetWillDisplayEntry(indexPath.section)
    }
```

Download image code:

```
    func downloadImage() {
            // 1
            image.value = Post.imageCache[self.imageFile!.name]

            if image is not downloaded yet, get it
            if (image.value == nil) {

                imageFile?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if let data = data {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data, scale: 2.0)!
                        self.image.value = image
                        // 2
                        Post.imageCache[self.imageFile!.name] = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    // MARK: PFSubclassing
    extension Post: PFSubclassing {
        static func parseClassName() -> String {
            return "Post"
        }

        override class func initialize() {
            var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
            dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
                // inform Parse about this subclass
                self.registerSubclass()
                // 1
                Post.imageCache = NSCacheSwift<String, UIImage>()
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my TableViewCell:

```
var post: Post? {
        didSet {
            postDisposable?.dispose()
            likeDisposable?.dispose()

            if let oldValue = oldValue where oldValue != post {

                oldValue.image.value = nil

            }

            if let post = post {

                postDisposable = post.image
                    .bindTo(postImageView.bnd_image)

                likeDisposable = post.likes
                    .observe { (value: [PFUser]?) -> () in

                        if let value = value {
                            //self.likesLabel.text = self.stringFromUserList(value)
                            self.likeButton.selected = value.contains(PFUser.currentUser()!)
                           // self.likesIconImageView.hidden = (value.count == 0)
                        } else {
                            //self.likesLabel.text = ""
                            self.likeButton.selected = false
                            //self.likesIconImageView.hidden = true

                        }}}}}
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You have to put all three views into a big scrollViews :)

Comment: @Breek Hmm, I tried with a UIScrollView but it didn't seem to work..More likely to be my fault! would you mind giving me a little example or something below in a answer?! Thanks anyways!

Comment: You asked virtually [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864981/how-to-make-full-viewcontroller-scroll/34867916#34867916) yesterday and then deleted it 3 hours ago. Why would someone bother to answer this question when you might just delete it again?

Comment: @Caleb yes you answered it. You ignored my comment, and it wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1

Add the header and tab as subviews to the content view. That way you get the scroll for free.

```
scrollView.contentView.addSubView(headerView)
scrollView.contentView.addSubView(tabView)
scrollView.contentView.addSubView(contentView)

let headerHight = 200
let tabHeight = 200
headerView.frame = CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, headerHight)
tabView.frame = CGRect(0, headerHight, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, tabHeight)
contentView.frame = CGRect(0, headerHight + tabHeight, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, contentHeight)
```

## Solution 2

Implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and move your header and tab on func `scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)`

Set up two constraints and outlets for the top position of the header and tab and change the constant value of the constraint to correspond to the `scrollView`s position

## Solution 3

Implement everything in a `tableView` and set the header as the `tableView.tableHeaderView`. It might be better to also include the tabbar as a part of the header if it's supposed to follow the scroll of the header anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is the code example (very ugly UI)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenWidth = view.frame.width
    let screenHeight = view.frame.height
    let subViewHeight = screenHeight / 3

    let mainView = UIScrollView(frame: view.frame)
    mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightTextColor()
    mainView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight + 100)
    view = mainView

    let firstView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: subViewHeight))
    firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let secondView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: subViewHeight, width: screenWidth, height: subViewHeight))
    secondView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let thirdView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: subViewHeight * 2, width: screenWidth, height: subViewHeight + 100))
    thirdView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
    thirdView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    view.addSubview(firstView)
    view.addSubview(secondView)
    view.addSubview(thirdView) 
}
```